# Is there any way to check user session once authenticated on navigating HTML pages in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I have two projects - one for Java Spring Services and other for Web UI.

I have the login functionality ready and as my views are in "html" extension kept in completely different folder

How do I check the **session**/authentication of the user **securely** while navigating the HTML pages and make the user return to the login page in case the session expires or no success session at all?

[image]

**The approach I do not want to follow :**

- I do not want to cluster my URL with session id's unless there is no better way
- I do not want to use Spring Security and my views are designed in
  HTML and AngularJS.
- Cookies again is not a secure way to do as anyone can get all the
  cookies from frontend.

Comment: Why cab you not rely on session ids?

Comment: I do not want to cluster my URL with the long session id

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a cookie with some required tokens, after successful user authentication.Then create a service like `/userAuth`, browser will automatically append your cookie(what ever sessionID, tokens,etc..) info to your http request headers.Based on the request header data you need to validate the user access or authorization.
if user is not authorized send 401 as status and on you angular $http failure method you need to emit/broadcast a logout event to redirect to appropriate page.

Answer (score 0):

You need, in Spring side, to setup an `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` which checks the login status and return an error code to the html side.

The Spring handlerInterceptorAdapter can be configured to intercept all of your controllers hand has a preHeandle method which can be used for checking user session or for login the user if your application is sessionless.

Then all of your WS will get no data.

Docs here

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html

If you want protect pages too you get to do some work on angular side in order to avoid the visualization if the pages WS return a proper error code (user not authorized). Or you can check for a token or a coockie.

Or otherwise you've to put your templates and their access under Spring Control
in a way that your interceptor will run before serving them.